# ExternalInterface problem with IE 6 7 8, when flash is added dynamically with JS

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I have a problem getting ExternalInterface.callBack(); to work in a specific case, when I add object and embed tags dynamically like this:

```
function createBannerObject(swfURL,flashVars, searchParams)
{
    /*  swfURL -- our template URL
        videoURL -- user video URL
        backURL -- background picture URL
        flashVars -- other user preferences -- string
        searchParam -- param for word search -- array  */

        var flashDiv = document.createElement('div');
        flashDiv.id = 'flashvideo';
        flashDiv.style.width='1px';
        flashDiv.style.height='1px';
        // id = myMovie, name = myMovie ------------------------//
        flashDiv.innerHTML = '<object id="myMovie" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%" align="left"><param name="bgcolor" value="#faa"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" /><param name="movie" value="'+swfURL+'" /><param name="flashvars" value="'+flashVars+'" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="opague" /><embed name="myMovie" src="'+swfURL+'" quality="high" width="100%" height="100%" align="left" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" bgcolor="#cccccc" wmode="opaque" flashvars="'+flashVars+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /></object>';
        //----------------------------------------------------------
        var search = ad_createDomElem('div',false);
        search.style.display = 'none';
        var searchWord = ad_createDomElem('p',{'id':'keyword'});
        searchWord.innerHTML = searchParams[0];
        var searchDiv = ad_createDomElem('p',{'id':'search'});
        searchDiv.innerHTML = searchParams[1];
        var regex1 = ad_createDomElem('p',{'id':'regex1'});
        regex1.innerHTML = searchParams[2];
        var regex2 = ad_createDomElem('p',{'id':'regex2'});
        regex2.innerHTML = searchParams[3];
        search.appendChild(searchWord);
        search.appendChild(searchDiv);
        search.appendChild(regex1);
        search.appendChild(regex2);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------
        flashDiv.appendChild(search);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------
        document.body.appendChild(flashDiv);
}
```

Now here is my getMovie function (just like everyone else's)

```
function getMovie(string)
{
    var M$ =  navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1;
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 9.0')) M$ = false; 
        return (M$ ? window : document)[string];
}
```

Here is the page it doesn't work on:

http://banners.adfox.ru/110811/adfox/156416/inDynamic.html

Here is a page it works on: the difference is that flash is not added dynamically:

http://banners.adfox.ru/110811/adfox/156416/onpage.html

All JS can be veiwed via source =)

Now about AS3 I use code:

```
Security.allowDomain('*');
ExternalInterface.addCallback("playVideoOnOpen", playVideoOnOpen);
ExternalInterface.addCallback("pauseVideoOnClose", pauseVideoOnClose);

function playVideoOnOpen()
{

}

function pauseVideoOnClose()
{

}
```

**I' ve managed to isolate the problem like this :**

http://banners.adfox.ru/110811/adfox/156416/dynamicAddEasy.html

Again all JS inside

Question: what could possibly go wrong when I add flash dynamically ? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you use swfobject.js to embed your swf then your problem will go away. I use it all the time with external interface and never have your problem.
You also didn't post the data that you are passing in to the function.

As you can see in the following code it is also much cleaner and self explaining.

```
html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function loaded() {
  var flashvars={}, params={}, attributes={}, tmp, version, width, height, container, flashObj;
  flashvars.userId    = "1234";

  params.menu = "true";
  params.quality = "high";
  params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
  params.allownetworking = "all";

  attributes.id = "test";
  attributes.name = "test";
  attributes.align = "middle";
  attributes.allowscriptaccess = "always";
  attributes.allownetworking = "all";

  tmp = "expressInstall.swf";
  version = "10.0.0";
  width = "100%";
  height = "100%";
  container = "replaceMe";// div tag to place the swf in
  flashObj = "test.swf?t=" + new Date().getTime(); // anticaching
  swfobject.embedSWF(flashObj, container, width, height, version, tmp, flashvars, params, attributes);
}

</script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="loaded()" onunload"doUnload( )">
    <div id="replaceMe">Loading content.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[EDIT]
I just noticed I left out something else.
Not sure if i ever tested this in IE9 but should work for you with 6-8

```
if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") >= 0){
    container = document;
}else{
    container = window;
}
var result = container[swf].flashCallBackFunction();
```

Comment: @Olga this is a purely JavaScript method of embeding. I do not see how it is not. The SWFObject.js is a 700 line file not a library. And JS files are cached so there is never a need for the user to reload it.

Comment: @Olga Sorry I added more to my post. I forgot the container reference functions.

Comment: Just want to add SWFObject.js is a 25kb file. That can be cut down by obfuscating it also

Comment: 5 10 100 banners on a page its still 700 lines of code. You don't add the code from SWFObject into your script you just give them the code that uses the functions from it. Seriously you need to functionalize something like that the only code you should be passing back to your "client" is a function call with parameters set from their options.

Comment: If yu wish, I can give you a good explanation why not, just not here, we are already creating spam!

Comment: Olga spam doesn't matter as you can see someone is already deleting your comments. Now please explain why you can not use the excepted and tested way of embedding.

Comment: The thing is, using SWF  Object means user will downloaded it as many times as many banners you have. Because there is no way I can be assuared there is SWFObject is on the page -- our client can manage banners separatly, and our company policy restricts using user instructions like "For this banner to work you shoul have on you page swfobjects ... etc..". So banner should be self-sufficient  crossbrowser solution. And including extra 10KB in all banners is not the way it can be.

Comment: Anyhow, thank you for your solution, but it does not solves my issue. Also I want to know WHY  IE does such strange things. At least I wnat to find any help with articles discribing why it is hapenning.

Comment: Olga did you try updating your getMovie function with the code I supplied? Yours is broken all IE use document reference